# Circular class dependency between "object" and "type"?

Tags: python, oop

I don't know how to ask this question. But my mind was crashed when I try this,

```
In [18]: isinstance(object, type)
Out[18]: True

In [19]: isinstance(object, object)
Out[19]: True

In [20]: isinstance(type, object)
Out[20]: True

In [21]: isinstance(type, type)
Out[21]: True
```

I can explain some thing from above:

1. object is a instance of type
2. object is a instance of object
3. type is a instance of object
4. type is a instance of type

I don't know how to evaluate above concept. Please any one explain the above concept.

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949; tl;dr version: It's because the function `type` is in fact a metaclass. `type` is the metaclass Python uses to create all classes behind the scenes.

Comment: @user2864740 If you understand my question description. Please change my question title related to that.

Comment: @dhana I did, and added a note for the original title was "false" :) `isinstance` "implies" a parent-child relationship, so parent-child/child-parent is a circular contradiction only, well, it is what it is here .. (Ruby has a similar self-tying knot at the root of the hierarchy.)

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for edit. If you have any idea about my question. Please give me an answer.